# How to calculate corresponding tile from Latlong with corresponding position in tile for specific zoom level for google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to create custom tiles on my server which will be used to show as overlay tile on google map.

For that, I need to calculate for given latlong and zoom level what is corresponding TileX, TileY on google map and on that tile what is xpos and ypos of that latlong.

I got some formula to find TileX and TileY but I didn't find formula to calculate xpos,ypos.

```
$xtile = floor((($lon + 180) / 360) * pow(2, $zoom));
$ytile = floor((1 - log(tan(deg2rad($lat)) + 1 / cos(deg2rad($lat))) / pi()) /2 * pow(2, $zoom));
```

Input: LatLong,ZoomLevel

Output: xpos,ypos

Answer (score 0):

from the [Documentation on MapTypes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#MapCoordinates)

```
// Normalizes the coords that tiles repeat across the x axis (horizontally)
// like the standard Google map tiles.
function getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom) {
  var y = coord.y;
  var x = coord.x;

  // tile range in one direction range is dependent on zoom level
  // 0 = 1 tile, 1 = 2 tiles, 2 = 4 tiles, 3 = 8 tiles, etc
  var tileRange = 1 << zoom;

  // don't repeat across y-axis (vertically)
  if (y < 0 || y >= tileRange) {
    return null;
  }

  // repeat across x-axis
  if (x < 0 || x >= tileRange) {
    x = (x % tileRange + tileRange) % tileRange;
  }

  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  };
}
```